# If Function is not working in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, conditional-statements

I had made a sheet to calculate factory workers timing and payment against working and over time.

First I made it in Excel 2013 and then I changed my Windows from 10 to 7 and also changed the software from *Office 2013* to *Kingssoft 2016*. After that it started to give false answer and i have tried my best to solve it but all goes useless.

Formula in L6 : `=if(k6=time(03,30,00),"120")` cell is formated as general and returning value is False... 
Cell K6 : `3:30` cell format is custom time.

i am attaching the screen shot for better conclusions

[image: Screanshot].

Comment: I've had this exact issue whilst developing - turned out the milliseconds were truncated. Do you work at millisecond granularity?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. It is not clear what you are asking us. It is also not clear which software you are using. Please [edit] your question to clarify. Beyond that, I do not understand why you are using that formula since it does not calculate the minutes. Nor does 3:30 equal 240 minutes.

Comment: try this `=TIME(HOUR(K6),MINUTE(K6),0)= TIME(3,30,0),120)`

Answer (score 1):

You should trim the time difference to whole seconds resolution to avoid (invisible) errors in the IF clause.
Use `=TRIM((F6-H6)*86400)/86400` in cell `K6` to cut off any amount smaller than a second.

Second, if you just want to show the difference in minutes (instead of hh:mm) then use `mm` in a custom format - you don't need to replace one numerical value with the same numerical value ('3:30' with '210').